# How to append (connect) strings to construct a new string?

Tags: javascript

I have a array of strings:

```
str[1]='apple';
str[2]='orange';
str[3]='banana';
//...many of these items
```

Then, I would like to construct a string variable which looks like **var mystr='apple,orange,banana,...'**, I tried the following way:

```
var mystr='';
for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
  mystr=mystr+","+str[i];
}
```

Which is of course not what I want, is there any efficient way to connect all this str[i] with comma?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use the built-in join function.

```
str.join(',');
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [join function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
var str = [];
str[0]='apple';
str[1]='orange';
str[2]='banana';

console.log(str.join(','));
```

would output:

```
apple,orange,banana
```

Answer (score 3):

The fastest and recommended way of doing this is with array methods:

```
var str = [];

str[1] = 'apple';
str[2] = 'orange';
str[3] = 'banana';

var myNewString = str.join(',');
```

There have been various performance tests showing that for building strings, using the array join method is far more performant than using normal string concatenation.

Answer (score 2):

You need this

```
var mystr = str.join(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

how about 'join()'?
e.g.

```
var newstr = str.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`array.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) i believe.

```
alert(['apple','orange','pear'].join(','));
```

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want?

```
var str = new Array(); //changed from new Array to make Eli happier
str[1]='apple';
str[2]='orange';
str[3]='banana';

var mystr=str[1];
for(var i=2; i<str.length; i++){
  mystr=mystr+","+str[i];
}
console.log(mystr);
```

would produce

```
apple,orange,banana
```

Comment: I don't even know what to say about this.

Comment: `var str = new Array;` <-- what is wrong with this statement?

Comment: @Eli just because it doesn't use the built in join() method doesn't make it wrong (and new Array still works even if it isn't totally correct), it just may not be as efficient. There have been times when I couldn't use the join() method as i needed to do more logic then just gluing together, in that case my solution would be a good one to have here so people can see a way to do it without join()